# Loading UIViewControllers via UIButton with delay functionality

Tags: iphone

I want `UIButton` playpauseAction to load `UIViewController` with some delay, maybe with an `NSTimer`.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

  if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

      [audioPlayer pause];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [audioPlayer play];

      [self displayviewsAction:sender];


  }   

}


- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{   
   PageOneViewController *viewController = [[PageOneViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

   [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[viewController release];
}
```

Can someone please tell me how that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**        `[self displayviewsAction:sender];`

**with**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; // 2 seconds
```